# What is "NING" browser? Gets suspicious results in my google analytics report

Tags: google-analytics

We have a commerical site with an average conversion about 2%.
Suprisingly we see that among users with NING browser (detected so by google analytics) - conversion is 220%. That is in average more than 2 order per one user session.

I am trying to understand what NING browser stands for? 
Most of the source in the traffic - is a direct type-in, rather than referals from some of NING-based websites (actualy, there are only 3% referal traffic with this browser and 97% is direct traffic, while on average direct traffic accounts only for ~ 20% of our website traffic).

Does anybody has a clue in which case google analytics will mark a hit with NING browser? And what this browser is?

Comment: It looks to be a spider or bot, which might explain some of the "conversions" if you're not seeing completed orders matching those numbers.

Comment: Here is a thread at WebmasterWorld about it.   Folks have chimed in with additional information such as the IP addresses and hosts that it uses.   However nobody really figured out what it is for: https://www.webmasterworld.com/search_engine_spiders/4516476.htm

Answer (score 2):

To send some data to google analytics through the Measurement protocol - you are can pass some parameters. And as our developers passed information about carts purchased offline afte the order was made online - they passed in this browser.